# transfer a sibling element in a reponse to a parameter in Ready API / SOAP UI

Tags: xpath, parameters, soapui, jsonpath

I have one REST endpoint which returns a response like this

```
[
 {
  "id": "dbfff519-e8f6-4db3-9e26-a4e9014dc360",
  "code": "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
  "name": "client-code-with-character-length-sixty",
 },
 {
  "id": "a673fb54-3503-4996-ba9b-a4e9014dc3ea",
  "code": "18MTH",
  "name": "18 Month",
},
  {
  "id": "60b781e3-4515-40f5-81ee-a4e9014dc400",
  "code": "2periods",
  "name": "I Have 2 Periods",
}...
```

etc.

I would like to be able to retrieve the ID where, for example, the code="2periods" UI can retrieve using either ResponseAsxml (with xpath) or Response with JSONPath. If I use the former I have managed to get the following to nearly retrieve my ID

`//Response[1]/e[code='2periods']/id`

BUT this looks like this

```
<id>0bc4aa5f-f8ab-4efe-b788-a4e9014dc45f</id>
```

And I don't know how to remove the start and end tags, the id has to be just the GUID.

I can't work out how to do something similar in the JSONPath - I've only managed to get something like

`$[3].id`

to work, but the order of the entities is not guaranteed in the test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ResponseAsXml` using the XPath to get only the id value without `<id>` tag just add `/text()` to your actual expression:

`//Response[1]/e[code='2periods']/id/text()`

If you want to do the same using `Response` property with JSONPath try with:

`$..[?(@.['code']=='2periods')].id[0]`

Hope it helps,

Comment: the JSONPath appears to resolve to the GUID plus extra [ and ] but the xpath works so I will stick with that - many thanks

Comment: @ZoëJobson to remove extra brackets you can add `[0]` to jsonpath expression `:)`